# Java: JavaFX Treeview to an XML

Tags: java, jaxb, treeview, javafx-8

I am a newbie to JavaFX
I am trying to save the JavaFX TreeView into a XML file.

```
Root
    |_ Child1
             |_Child1.1
             .
             .
             .

    |_ Child2
             |_Child2.1
             .
             .
    |_ Child3
    .
    .
    .
```

When I save file it saves the above structure into an XML file:

```
<root>
<node>Root</node>
<children>
       <child>
       <node>child1</node>
       <children>
             <child>
                <node>child1.1</node>
             </child>
       </children>
       </child>
       <child>
       <node>child2</node>
       <children>
             <child>
                <node>child2.1</node>
             </child>
       </children>
       </child>
       <child>
       <node>child3</node>
       </child>
 </children>
</root>
```

I am mapping the object to my JAXB pojo at every new TreeItem addition. The problem I am encountering is that I have no way to know the position of the new TreeItem so I add the new Item to the end of my JAXB object the makes the final XML structure wrong.

How can I capture the position of the newly added TreeItem?

[image: Add Component from UI can be at any position]

My JAXB pojo looks like this:

```
public class Node {
      private String attributes;
      private List<Node>
}
```

When a child is added I add a new node to the `List<Node>`.
As shown in the image above if the node is not added to the end of the list in the UI my logic of adding new node to `List<Node>` doesnt work.

Comment: what/ho/where is the new TreeItem added? How comes you don't know the position? And which position - in the view or in your backing data? Please clarify, best with a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I updated the question I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: repeating: for best help, please show the code - in the form of a SSCCE (your favourite search engine will help you find out what the acronym stands for if you don't know already :)